# Extracting multiple info from string to create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'info':{0:'1cr1:782906:F:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0',
                           1:'5cr1:782946:G:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0'}})
```

that looks like this

```
    info
0   1cr1:782906:F:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0
1   5cr1:782946:G:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0
```

I'd like to extract the info between the 1st & 2nd colon, 4th & 5th , 6th and 7th and info after the 7th colon and append to new columns

The result should look like this.

```
    info                               A       B    C   D
0   1cr1:782906:F:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0    782906   1    0   0
1   5cr1:782946:G:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0    782946   1    0   0
```

I believe the following should give me the 1st three columns but I'm getting an expected a 1D array error and I'm unsure how to account for the 4th column in the regular expression

```
df['A','B','C'] = df['info'].str.extract(r'(:(\d*):)', expand=True)
```

https://regex101.com/r/83aj0l/1

Comment: try using `r'(?<=:)\d+'` in your regex. It gets only the numbers and asserts that there is a colon behind the number.

Comment: This selects the number but doesn't make them capture groups. Running in additional parentheses just appends the 1st value to one column ```df['A','B','C'] = df['info'].str.extract(r'((?<=:)\d+)', expand=True)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

- Use [`pd.Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with `'(?<=:)(\d+)'` to get each sequence of digits preceded by a colon ([pattern explanation](https://regex101.com/r/6NcedY/1)).
- Use [`df.squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) to get the resulting `df` with 1 column as a `Series` and apply [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to pivot the result.
- Finally, use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename the columns and use [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to attach the result to `df['info']`.

```
df = (df.join(df['info']
              .str.extractall('(?<=:)(\d+)')
              .squeeze()
              .unstack()
              .rename(columns={k: v for k, v in enumerate([*'ABCD'])})
              )
      )

df

                             info       A  B  C  D
0  1cr1:782906:F:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0  782906  1  0  0
1  5cr1:782946:G:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0  782946  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but you have to do it column by column, and it is not the cleanest looking solution though

```
df['A'] = df['info'].astype("str").apply(lambda x: [e for e in x.split(':') if e.isdigit()][0])
df['B'] = df['info'].astype("str").apply(lambda x: [e for e in x.split(':') if e.isdigit()][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach that could work. First, convert your `info` column into a list of values by splitting on the `:` character.

```
df["info"] = df["info"].apply(lambda x: x.split(":"))
```

Once that's done, you can use `.apply(pd.Series)` create a bunch of columns,  one for each element of the list. Each row gets converted into a `pd.Series`, which means the output is a dataframe. `info_df = df['info'].apply(pd.Series)`.

If it's true that every value in `info` always has the same number of colon-separated substrings, then a shorthand to get exactly what you want is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'info':{0:'1cr1:782906:F:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0',
                           1:'5cr1:782946:G:He:1:Ho1:0:Ho2:0'}})

df[["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]] = df["info"].apply(pd.Series)
```